# combine multiple grep pipes into one

Tags: grep, pipe

I am trying to filter out multiple sets of search results, and I can already get what I need by using multiple `grep` pipes:

```
find -name *.txt | grep -v expr1 | grep -v expr2 | grep -v expr3 | grep -v expr4
```

This syntax seems oddly inefficient; I'd expect to be able to condense this into something like:

```
find -name *.txt | grep -v 'expr1|expr2|expr3|expr4'
```

Is there a simpler form I can use to avoid writing out multiple `grep` pipes?

Comment: Simplified .. Can't one just `grep -E 'expr1|expr2|expr3' *.txt`?

Comment: With GNU grep: `| grep -Ev 'expr1|expr2|expr3|expr4'` or `| grep -v 'expr[1-4]'`?

Comment: thanks! `grep -Ev` is the switch I was looking for.  feel free to re-post as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

POSIX `grep` doesn't have this capability of asserting multiple words per line. If you jave `gnu grep` then you can do this by using negative lookahead like this:

```bash
grep -P '^(?!.*expr1)(?!.*expr2)(?!.*expr3)(?!.*expr4)' *.txt
```